# Genre du terme «espace»

Tags: genre, terminologie, typographie

Lorsque j’étais à la petite école, toujours mes enseignants nous disaient « un espace » pour quelque type de distance à insérer entre des mots, des chiffres, des blocs de textes ou de calculs, des sections de raisonnement, etc.

Plus vieux, j’ai appris qu’en typographie, le terme était [féminin](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Espace_(typographie)#Genre_du_mot), ce que m’ont confirmé de nombreuses ressources linguistiques et encyclopédiques. *Le Trésor de la langue française* nous affirme cependant qu’une [espace](http://cnrtl.fr/definition/espace) typographique est à la base une petite lame de métal insérée entre les caractères, et éventuellement, par métonymie, le blanc résultant de l’usage de cette lame.

Si la [typographie](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/typographie) est un art de la composition et de la mise en page initialement très lié à la technologie de l’imprimerie, l’informatique l’a désormais repris à son compte, modifiant considérablement nombre de ses méthodes, mais empruntant néanmoins beaucoup à sa terminologie *(espace fine, par exemple)* et y dérivant certains termes nouveaux *(notamment l’espace insécable, féminine)*.

Quand je publie en ligne, par exemple cette question que je compose ici, je suppose que les espaces qui apparaîtront entre les mots sont des produits d’une mise en page de mon choix, avec les contraintes imposées par Stack Exchange, et que donc nous pourrions dire qu’elles sont féminines. Est-ce un raisonnement valide ?

Qu’en est-il alors de l’écriture manuscrite ? Celle à laquelles mes enseignants faisaient allusion lorsqu’ils nous disaient de ***laisser un espace*** entre les mots. Doit-on comprendre que l’espace *(masculin)* que je plaçais alors pour séparer mes mots, serait devenu féminin lors d’une impression typographique ?

Et puisque aujourd’hui beaucoup d’écoles font écrire un premier jet à la main, mais requièrent aussi un produit final informatisé, doit-on penser que tous les espaces de la feuille manuscrite sont devenus toutes les espaces de la feuille imprimée ?

Quand donc s’effectue le changement de genre ?

Comment: Cet·te espace transgenre et pédant·e que quasiment personne ne respecte me gène. Si ça ne tenait qu'à moi, j'aurais laissé son féminin disparaître à l'instar de la petite lame métallique éponyme et je l'aurais rétabli dans sa masculinité par une réforme de l'orthographe...

Answer (score 2):

La distinction entre *un espace* et *une espace* est subtile lorsqu'il s'agit d'écriture. On utilise *une espace* (un élément typographique) pour laisser *un espace* (un espace blanc) entre les mots.

Lorsque l'on parle d'écriture manuscrite, on ne peut pas vraiment parler d'*une espace*, parce que l'espace entre les mots n'est pas un élément typographique. C'est juste un morceau de page qu'on laisse en blanc.

En typographie mécanique, *une espace* est un élément physique qui sert à séparer les mots. C'est aussi par métonymie le symbole vierge qui apparaît dans le texte imprimé.

En typographie informatique, *une espace* est un caractère qui sert à séparer les mots. Mais outre que beaucoup de gens utilisent « un espace » parce qu'ils ne savent pas que le mot est féminin dans ce sens, il y a une bonne raison de dire « un espace » : c'est un raccourci pour « un caractère espace ».

Le seul cas où *une espace* s'impose est si l'on parle manifestement d'un symbole typographique. C'est essentiellement le cas quand on parle d'un type particulier d'espace : *une espace insécable*, *une espace fine*, etc. Mais même dans ce cas le masculin se justifie aussi si l'on voit l'expression comme un raccourci pour « un caractère … ».

Answer (score 1):

L'espace en typographie est une petite chose en plomb, donc l'espace entre deux caractère ne peut être considéré, stricto sensu,  comme une espace .. L'usage est d'utiliser le mot au masculin.

Answer (score 0):

Je pense que la proximité sémantique avec son homonyme l'espace, **n.m.**,  au sens de distance entre deux objets, donc pourquoi pas deux caractères rendus à l'écran, peut tout aussi bien l'emporter à l'usage. Et c'est d'ailleurs ce qui s'est produit.